# How create many to many mapping tables automatically in SqlAlchemy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I am writing a framework to help people handle different data models in a database efficiently (meaning bulk operations). I would like to create a base class for many to many relationships, that can be used like so:

```
from sqlalchemy import MetaData
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()    

class CustomBase(Base):
    __abstract__ = True
    metadata = MetaData()

class CustomManyToManyBase(CustomBase):
    __abstract__ = True

class Parent(CustomBase):
   __tablename__ = 'parents'
   id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

class Child(CustomBase):
   __tablename__ = 'children'
   id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

class Family(CustomManyToManyBase):
   models = (Parent, Child)
```

and then it would automatically get the primary keys of the models and create the necessary columns for an association table, equivalent with this (as if I wrote the following):

```
class Family(CustomBase):
   parent_id = ForeignKey('parent.id')
   child_id = ForeignKey('child.id')
```

In my understanding, I cannot use `relationship()`, as it is omitted with bulk operations, but I can easily extract key pairs from my data, and use `bulk_insert_mappings`. I need the model classes for other generic data manipulation tasks, so I thought that there may be a way to use that information to create the necessary columns as well.

What if I would like to store additional information in that association table?

The whole point of this is to provide a base class with the bulk operations prewritten, so novice users of SQLAlchemy can work efficiently too (they may even be unaware of SQLAlchemy).

Comment: I also examined the `declared_attr` decorator, but with that, I am stucked with predefined attribute names on the base class.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to create such class, but not as a base class, rather a mixin:

```
from sqlalchemy.inspection import inspect
from sqlalchemy import Column, ForeignKey, Integer, Table

class ManyToManyMixin:
    @classmethod
    def __table_cls__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        return Table(
            *args,
            *[Column(
                '{}_{}'.format(model.__name__.lower(), col.name),
                col.type,
                ForeignKey(col),
                primary_key=True
              ) for model in cls.models for col in inspect(model).primary_key]
            **kwargs
        )
```

which can be used as:

```
class Family(ManyToManyMixin, CustomBase):
    __tablename__ = 'families'
    other_value = Column(Integer) # just to show that it does not cause any restrictions

    models = (Parent, Child)
```

You can find details [here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/declarative/api.html#table-cls).